# Why array push not working in my function?

Tags: javascript

I've made a simple function that adds a value to the array in javascript and then returns them.

What I can't return is the added value. What am I doing wrong?

It returns "c" instead of 3.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0rapj8y8/2/

Code:

```js
function test(a, b, c) {
  var array = [a, b];
  array.push('c');
  alert(array);
}
test(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: `array.push(c);` - no `''` - when you enclose `c` in quotes in it is treated as the string literal `c`, since you want to push the value referred by the variable `c` don't enclose it

Comment: Hmm..my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I've made it a string. Saw that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very basic language syntax issue. Why do you quote a variable name?

```
array.push('c');
```

That is a character `c`, not your variable `c`

```
array.push(c);  // that is now your variable c
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9ew6k1k/)**

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes

```
function test(a, b, c) {
  var array = [a, b];
  array.push(c);
  alert(array);
}
test(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks. Saw my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove Quote in push fuction as follows**

```js
function test(a, b, c) {
  var array = [a, b];
  array.push(c);
  alert(array);
}
test(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks. Saw my mistake.